# How to split a string into the first character and the rest?

Tags: string, rust

This is the code I currently have:

```
fn split_first_char(s: &str) -> Option<(char, &str)> {
    let mut char_indices = s.char_indices();
    let (_, c) = char_indices.next()?;
    let i = match char_indices.next() {
        Some((i, _)) => i,
        None => s.len(),
    };
    Some((c, s.split_at(i).1))
}
```

Is there an easier or built-in way to do the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found another more elegant solution:

```
fn split_first_char(s: &str) -> Option<(char, &str)> {
    let mut chars = s.chars();
    match chars.next() {
        Some(c) => Some((c, chars.as_str())),
        None => None,
    }
}
```

or

```
fn split_first_char(s: &str) -> Option<(char, &str)> {
    let mut chars = s.chars();
    chars.next().map(|c| (c, chars.as_str()))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, but you can make this lot shorter:

```rust
fn split_first_char(s: &str) -> Option<(char, &str)> {
    s.chars().next().map(|c| (c, &s[c.len_utf8()..]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Rust 1.50 you can use [split_first()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_first)

```rust
"My String".chars().collect::<Vec<char>>().split_first();
```

This results in:

```
Option<(&char, &[char])>
```

While the type isn't exactly `Option<(char, &str)>` it may be close enough to what you are looking for.

Comment: That method is for `[T]`, not `str`, as is asked here

Comment: I clarified with an example. Thank you.

Comment: Your code is linear in the length of the string, collecting all the chars into a Vector, then only taking the first char. This may be optimized away, but you don't really want to have to think about that.